# How can I apply the authentification 2 factors using azure ad in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am already using authentication Azure Ad in my application, but I would like to apply also two factors authentication to the login process. I am not find out any tutorial about that specific topic.

I've already tried to implement some changes into Azure Active Directory but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Multi-Factor Authentication is something you do on Azure AD, not on your application.
You can see this tutorial as a reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa

But I guess that the problem is that this is not available in every AAD. There are specific AAD plans that have this feature enabled. (i.e. you need to pay for it). You can see the plans that have it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing